# Dependency install errors in composer

Tags: php, composer-php, hhvm

I've been a problem when i try to install any dependency using composer.

I tried to use the `composer update` or `composer update`. I need to install a chart dependency to my application in Laravel.

When i try to execute any action, show this message below.

```
This package requires php 7.2.18 but your HHVM version does not satisfy that requirement.
```

I cannot find a answer to this problem on the internet. I try to install a more recently version of HHVM but i didn't succeed.

Comment: What do you get when you execute `php -v` on your terminal ?

Comment: have you tried running the composer install with the --ignore-platform-reqs flag?

Comment: I got it fixed. The problem is in the current PHP versioning in composer.json. The problem occurred because i was using my colleague's git repository and i did not adjust my PHP version with his. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately HHVM no longer supports vanilla PHP. You should use the vanilla (Zend) PHP runtime, and should not install HHVM as `php` on your system.

More information on both PHP deprecation and Composer is here: https://hhvm.com/blog/2019/02/11/hhvm-4.0.0.html

Comment: It's a good answer. I fixed my problem changing my PHP version in composer.json. Because my colleague's change the PHP version and i not update. Thanks for the help.